# Imported function undefined on first few executions of a Reducer

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I'm really baffled by this odd behaviour. I'm importing a small utility function called `now`, which is sometimes `undefined`, and at other points in the execution of my application is working just as it should do.

So here is my `now` function:

```
const now = () => Date.now();

export { now };
```

It's super simple and designed to make mocking easier for our end to end testing. Ultimately I want to use this to set the initial state (as you can see by the commented out line below). But for debugging purposes I'm logging from my reducer:

```
import { now } from '../../../utils';

/**
 * {
 *     currentDate: 01/01/2020,
 * }
 */
const defaultState = {
    // currentDate: new Date(now()),
};

/**
 * Defines a Reducer to handle schedule changes
 * @param  {Object} state  The current state of the application
 * @param  {Object} action The action and payload that we want to trigger in the reducer
 * @return {Object}        The new state
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line default-param-last
const scheduleReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    console.log(now);
    switch (action.type) {
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export { scheduleReducer };
```

So here I'd expect `now` to either log as a function, or if I've got the import path wrong to be `undefined` (and have linting errors). This is the output I actually get:

[image]

I don't understand how this can be possible, when I'm trying to set it the value within `initialState` Jest complains that `now` is undefined too, so there's something really weird going on. Can anyone shed some light on this?

---

**UPDATE**

So something I didn't mention which I've deemed important is the export from the `utils` directory which has an `index.js` file that looks like this:

```
export * from './request';
export * from './now';
```

So we've managed to determine the following. If I log the full contents of the `utils` import, with the above import style then the import is empty:

```
import { now } from '../../../utils';
import * as index from '../../../utils';

console.log(index);
console.log(now);
```

[image]

If however I change the first import:

```
import { now } from '../../../utils/now';
import * as index from '../../../utils';

console.log(index);
console.log(now);
```

[image]

I don't understand why this is the case, it obviously works around my problem but I'm still interested to understand why the imports behave this way if anyone understands the reasons behind this?

On closer inspection, some of the imports had "cycles" in them, I'm guessing that this could cause a problem. I don't really know how cycles are processed/handles (or not) during imports.

Comment: Does `export const now = () => Date.now();` work?

Comment: @HMR No, it behaves in exactly the same way

Comment: @HMR I have added an update however, I've found a way to make it work. Still quite confusing though as to why it exhibits this behaviour.